# Android KitKat HttpURLConnection disconnect AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, httpurlconnection, android-4.4-kitkat

In my application, I download a file using an [HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) in an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).  If the file takes too long to download, then I want cancel it; and I do this by closing the stream and calling [disconnect()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#disconnect%28%29) on the `HttpURLConnection` object.  The code has worked flawlessly for years in Android.  However, now that KitKat is out, issues have popped up.  Specifically, the `disconnect()` call itself takes several seconds or more to complete.  In pre-KitKat devices, it took a millisecond or less.  What is really strange is that when I perform the disconnect call on a separate thread, then it is really fast again.  So it has to be an issue with calling it in the `AsyncTask`'s `doInBackground` method.  One thing to note is that my `AsyncTask` does have a `Looper.prepare()` call.

Does anyone know what the difference between KitKat and other Android versions is?  I combed through the change lists and did not see anything related to this issue.

Comment: I'm seeing a similar issue; I've done some investigation and it's a change in the way streams are closed. I've gone into more detail [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20306498/unable-to-close-chunkedinputstream-quickly-on-android-4-4-kitkat) - unfortunately I don't have a fix yet.

Comment: Same result, also disconnect on separate thread makes same delay for me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Kitkat uses okhttp instead of the previous HTTPConnection implementation, or at least this is the case on Nexus devices with the official update.

Comment: How did you determine this?  I looked through the source code and see that the okhttp libraries have been in the source [since 4.2](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/okhttp/+/android-4.2_r1).

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/okhttp/+log/ The changes implemented in `2231db3` do not exist in Android 4.3 (regardless of what the tags say); they do exist in Android 4.4.

Comment: Ah okay. I'm still curious why the behavior would be different in an AsyncTask than on a separate thread.

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to [persistent connections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection), and attempt of HttpURLConnection to reuse same HTTP connection, thus when closing connection or InputStream, it tries to consume all remaining data by reading them and discarding. Then same HTTP connection is ready for next command.

There seems to be some new implementation in KitKat that makes things different and causes problems.

I try to stream video data over HTTP, with occasional seeking which results in closing connection and initiating new one. Certainly I don't need fetching of video stream up to end in this case.

I tried to call

```
HttpURLConnection con;
con.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
```

but it didn't make difference.

However, I tried using same code with [DefaultHttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html) and calling

```
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(uri);
get.addHeader("Connection", "close");
```

then finally closing InputStream of connection is fast, which I proved in debugger by stepping into ConnectionReuseStrategy.keepAlive and seeing that server returned Connection:close and DefaultHttpClient didn't try to reuse connection and reading till end.

So you can use DefaultHttpClient or find a way to make HttpURLConnection to just close connection without reading rest.

Answer (score -1):

Why dont you try using apache lib http connection

something like this, inside your async task

```
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://server.com");
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    if(response!=null)
    {
        final  String responseBody =EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        if (responseBody != null) 
        {  



        }

    }
```

Comment: That was silently deprecated a couple years ago and Google recommends using HttpURLConnection.  See this [blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html).

Comment: I know there are a couple ports out there of the latest Apache stuff for Android, but I feel the raw Java stuff should just work.

Comment: Hi Chris , thanks for the info, i am aware that, it is not supported by google, although works great, generally i prefer to use apache library as it is faster then standard java http connection. also no need for while readline coding part. webpage is returned straight as string. in my case it works great, i would highly recommend it.

Comment: I tested, and using HttpClient and closing InputStream of response makes same long delay (15 seconds) on my device.  borg666: format your code example properly!

Comment: @PointerNull, We do not take orders here, make sure you ask it kindly next time, you are not in a pub.

Comment: @borg666: my apologies, certainly I was stressed with some hard programming ;)