# Unable to close ChunkedInputStream quickly on Android 4.4 KitKat

Tags: java, android, okhttp

I've got an Android Daydream that displays a stream of tweets using Twitter4j's streaming implementation. This works fine on Android 4.2 and 4.3. On 4.4 however, I cannot quickly close the stream (in `onDreamingStopped`).

I'm getting [this stacktrace](https://gist.github.com/adamsp/019ab66bf43489927332) but the `NetworkOnMainThreadException` isn't the problem.

The problem appears to be related to [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38817), around connection reuse. [This OkHttp changeset](https://github.com/square/okhttp/commit/04d742bd3d6ce8ad24b21f2be2d6f3ea5f8a35a5#diff-d50d214c3607bcfa12dfcd5ef1abed85) (which gets merged into Android [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/okhttp/+/2231db3e6bb54447a9b14cf004a6cb03c373651c)) changes the way that `close` behaves on `ChunkedInputStream`. Instead of simply marking itself as "closed" and then disconnecting the socket if there was still more data to be read, it now attempts to discard the stream first to enable quick reuse of the socket. If it fails to discard the stream, it then disconnects the socket as before.

The reason I'm now getting a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` is because (as you see from the stack trace) discarding the stream now attempts to read from the stream. That's easy enough to fix - I just drop it in an `AsyncTask` when closing my Daydream and forget about it.

The problem is that the stream isn't being discarded within the timeout set. Looking at the [`HttpTransport#discardStream` method of the latest version of the source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/okhttp/+/master/okhttp/src/main/java/com/squareup/okhttp/internal/http/HttpTransport.java), it specifies a 100ms timeout on the socket (the original commit specified 30ms), then tries to read from the stream (`Util.skipAll`) to empty the buffer. However I'm seeing a multiple-second delay around the [`BufferedInputStream.read()`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/master/luni/src/main/java/java/io/BufferedInputStream.java) call. The length of this delay seems to vary.

This isn't a huge problem - since I now have to close this stream off the UI thread anyway, I'm not causing the `onDreamingStopped` call to take a long time to return (which was causing the daydream to stay on the screen for a long time after pressing back/home - my initial bug report which caused me to follow this rabbit hole). However, it does leave this connection hanging around for a while after it's supposed to be closed.

I've tested how long it takes to close the stream with two Twitter accounts of varying activity levels. The first one didn't see any activity in the time I was trying to close the stream, and I was consistently seeing the call take around 30 seconds. The second account has much more activity on it, and the time to close the stream was much more varied on this one - anywhere from 1.5 to 30 seconds. It appears to close instantly when a new tweet comes in (a new chunk is written to the stream).

**Why am I seeing this delay in closing a stream on KitKat? Why does it not respect the 100ms timeout that's being set?**

This is similar to [Android KitKat HttpURLConnection disconnect AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20104404/android-kitkat-httpurlconnection-disconnect-asynctask) - although that's presumably using a `FixedLengthInputStream` under the hood, the same change has been applied to the `close` method of that class.

Answer (score 5):

This was a bug in OkHttp. Fix is [here](https://github.com/square/okhttp/pull/430). If you don't mind including the OkHttp jar in your application, you can work-around this problem until AOSP is updated to include the fix.

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory(okHttpClient);
```

The fix was not merged in time for OkHttp 1.3; you'll need to wait for a later release or build the `jar` yourself.

Comment: Thanks Jesse, appreciate this. Will build & include this tonight, was  pretty problematic for me in KitKat!

Comment: This isn't working for me, unfortunately; I'm seeing the same behaviour as previously. I've tried building from your fix branch, as well as the latest changes from master. JDK 1.7.0_45, Android 4.4.2 target. [My changes](https://gist.github.com/adamsp/2c32ddd9d3cec1985c6a).

Comment: I checked Twitter4J as well, to see if that was setting its own stream  handler; nothing there. It's hanging on the [`BufferedInputStream.read`](https://github.com/square/okhttp/pull/430/files#diff-852ddaac3fda31af3b33f3e85ca939f0R298) call/

Comment: @AdamS that's strange. We've got a test case that tries to reproduce exactly your case. Can you get me a thread dump of the failed request? I'd really like to get this fixed!
https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp/src/test/java/com/squareup/okhttp/internal/http/URLConnectionTest.java#L1137

Comment: I've just left the city for a few days sorry! Will get you one early next week though.

Comment: Alright Jesse, I've made some progress. I'm getting a different issue now, on all OkHttp builds since Jan 18. I've [gone into detail here](https://gist.github.com/adamsp/7ffd33906abf9b1a5df3).

Comment: Righto fixed that in source and I'm still seeing what I had above; it's hanging on the `BufferedInputStream.read` call. Hit pause in the debugger while it was trying to close and [this is the stack](https://gist.github.com/adamsp/9274a14e54af18505d07).

Comment: Hmm. That stack suggests a chunked encoding problem. Weird. Got the URL?

Comment: Just https://userstream.twitter.com/1.1/user.json (which obviously won't work without auth...)